# Anyway to redirect to previous URL after registration in Joomla?

Tags: joomla, redirect, joomla1.5, joomla-extensions

I am developing a component that required login at some level, then if user is not logged in, I placed a login link, that take user to login page with following in query string.

```
return=<?php echo base64_encode($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);?>
```

After login, it comes back to that page, but is there some way to tackle this if user is not registered and user starts registering? Is there some way to do this without changing some thing in Joomla it self? like by just setting some thing in cookie e.t.c. Or I will need to change some thing in Joomla Registration component or module. Or is there some plugin for that?

Any response will be appreciated, please tell what ever way you know so that it may give me some better clue.

Answer (score 0):

In your component you could try to store the referrer in the Joomla! session - I don't believe the session changes or is replaced during login. *I haven't had time to try this but it should work.*

To Save:

```
$session = JFactory::getSession();
$session->set('theReferrer', $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], 'mycomponentname');
```

To Retrieve:

```
$session = JFactory::getSession(); 
$redirectTo = $session->get('theReferrer', '', 'mycomponentname');
```

Then you can just use a `setRedirect` before you return.

```
$this->setRedirect($redirectTo);
```

Comment: So to retrieve I must modify after login file, mean joomla itself don't have such thing buitin

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with a plugin (at least in Joomla 3.x - not sure how far back this will work off-hand). Key here is the onUserAfterSave event, which tells you whether the user is new or existing.

I wrote the code below some time ago, so can't recall the exact reason the redirect could not be done from within the onUserAfterSave event handler, but I think the redirect is subsequently overridden elsewhere in the core Joomla user management code if you try to do it from there, hence saving a flag in the session and checking it in a later event handler.

```
class PlgUserSignupRedirect extends JPlugin
{
    public function onUserAfterSave($user, $isnew, $success, $msg)
    {
        $app = JFactory::getApplication();

        // If the user isn't new we don't act
        if (!$isnew) {
            return false;
        }

        $session = JFactory::getSession();
        $session->set('signupRedirect', 1);

        return true;
    }

    function onAfterRender() {
        $session = JFactory::getSession();
        if ($session->get('signupRedirect')) {
            JFactory::getApplication()->redirect($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
            $session->clear('signupRedirect');
        }
    }
}
```